# Unexpected overwriting of Variable values within VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I have returned to VBA after about a year absence and I have been completely perplexed by an issue I have encountered. I have written multiple scripts that follow the below logic so I'm stumped as to what is going on here. If I am overlooking something glaringly obvious then I'm happy to swallow my pride...

The below extract of code is fairly simple in that it stores variables to builds a text string and creates a text file. It seems that a number of variables are being replaced by a later variable. As an example `STKQTY = 5` and `Flg = 1`. As I step through the code, `STKQTY` correctly returns 5 with the next line correctly returning 1 for `Flg`, however `STKQTY` now equals 1 having been replaced by the value of `FLG`.

You will notice I have used a the direct reference earlier in the `If` function and this seemed to work so the issue seems to be caused by the variables.

```vb
x = 2
Fstr = ""

Do While D.Range("A" & x) <> ""
    If D.Range("A" & x) = "E" Then
        LStr = "E;" & D.Range("B" & x) & vbNewLine
    ElseIf D.Range("A" & x) = "L" Then
        SheetID = D.Range("C" & x).Value
        LStr = "L;" & D.Range("B" & x) & ";" & D.Range("C" & x) & vbNewLine
    Else
        Line = D.Range("D" & x)
        Site = D.Range("E" & x)
        PACQTY = D.Range("F" & x)
        STKQTY = D.Range("G" & x)
        Flg = D.Range("H" & x)
        SKU = D.Range("I" & x)
        LocID = D.Range("L" & x)
        If STKQTY = 0 Then
            Lot = ""
            LocID = ""
            Sta = ""
        ElseIf STKQTY > 0 And LocID = "" Then
            Lot = D.Range("J" & x)
            LocID = "STOCKTAKE"
            Sta = "A"
        Else
            Lot = D.Range("J" & x)
            Sta = D.Range("M" & x)
        End If
        
        LStr = "S;" & SesID & ";" & SheetID & ";" & Line & ";" & Site & ";" & PACQTY & ";" & STKQTY & ";" &     Flg & ";" & SKU & ";" & Lot & ";" & LocID & ";" & Sta
```

Replacing the variables with direct cell references worked but I'll be using the variable for other functions so needs to remain efficient.

Comment: Have you declared the variables? Are they used anywhere else in your code?

Comment: Is this the full code fragment? I suggest in the first instance using `Option Explicit` and also properly declaring yout variables i.e. `Dim x as Integer`

Comment: Quote: "but I'll be using the variable for other functions" - why? Public variables can get "overwritten" by all sorts - stick to utilising scope